# .htaccess not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this following in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  (.*)\.php$ index.php
```

I just want to rewrite every .php file accessed to index.php, changing everything after the first slash. I wonder why it isn't working. Been stuck in this for hours now. :|

Comment: Have you verified that you are allowed to set these options in your `.htaccess` file? See the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: ^Yes. In fact, I wrote a different rule earlier on the same .htaccess file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will use index.php as the internal script for the request (with the original relative url appended as a query string to index.php), it will not redirect to index.php.

Also make sure that you have the proper options and allowoverride set for this directory to be able to use rewriterules.. Which includes needing FollowSymlinks.

Test with -

```
Options All
AllowOverride All
```

...in httpd.conf or where the Directory is defined. Restart Apache.

Make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded.

And also check Apache's error log.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. No errors, either.

Comment: @SFault, okay, I've updated the answer with more info.

Comment: @SFault, place `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` at the top of index.php to test if it's not getting to this file.

Comment: index.php gets opened and there's nothing in the error logs.

Comment: @SFault, "index.php gets opened"... That sounds like the above rules work then?